# Django model field which refers to ImageField of another model

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class A(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   a_bg_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='./bg/')

class A_B(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   b_bg_img = # this should just refer to A's a_bg_img field
```

`b_bg_img` should just refer to `a_bg_img` Field so that I dont save one Image twice. can I just say:

```
b_bg_img = models.TextField()
```

and then save there only the link to Image in `a_bg_img` ?

Comment: Why don't you use a ForeignKey?

Comment: @DanielRoseman foreignkey isnot too much for just a imagefield reference?

Comment: @doniyor what do you mean by 'too much'.  A foreign key is pretty lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image associated with a class A object, then you can easily retrieve the path of that image or url of that image using `.path`( or `get_path()`) or `.url`.

For example:

```
a = A.objects.get(id=1)
print(a.a_bg_img.path)
'/path/to/image/in/your/local/drive/image.jpg'
print(a.a_bg_img.get_path())
'/path/to/image/in/your/local/drive/image.jpg'
print(a.a_bg_img.url)
'/url/to/your/image'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the django signals [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/signals/#post-save) to perform actions after the models save()

How ?

1. create a signals.py file in your app
2. import it in `__init__.py` of your main app folder
3. Inside the signals.py app create function like below:

---

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=A)
def my_action(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Your function magic
```

Comment: "how should I use it?" was meant how it should solve my problem. the technic wasnot the question and is nothing new ;)

Comment: use the instance inside your function to create or edit a B model

Comment: sorry, but I dont see anything relevant to my question in your answer